# Spotipy does not work on remote server due to authentication

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

My program works fine when I run it on my personal machine, however when I try to run the exact same code on a remote server on PebbleHost, I get the following errors:

```
Couldn´t read cache at: .cache
Couldn´t write token to cache at: .cache
```

From what I've gathered this is because I need to authenticate my server for spotify, however I don't know how I can do that when I don't have access to the browser that is supposed to pop up. The only thing I have access to is the console, where does show the url I need to visit to do the authentication. However opening this url on my personal machine does nothing.

I don't have a website, should I set the redirect uri to an ip address instead of using `localhost`? If so how do I determine what ip address to use and what steps do I take?

Comment: Its "just" oauth2.  You can program the auth exchange without needing a graphical browser. But it is a PITA.
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/

Comment: But how do I do that? I'm completely lost

Comment: Sorry I have never used `Spotipy`.  Did you have a go at the examples?
[Headless](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/headless.py) and [client flow](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/client_credentials_flow.py)

Comment: I see you can't access user info with the client credentials.  If you want that then what about the [auth flow docs](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#authorization-code-flow)